# Can my spouse holding single entry germany Dependent D visa travel to other schengen states?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, customs-and-immigration

Can my spouse, who has a single entry Germany Dependent D, visa travel to other Schengen states? Her visa is valid for 6 months same as mine. I do have employment Germany visa and my spouse will be accompanying me to Germany.